# How can I place the symbols in correct places to the code?

Tags: python

I've tried so many times to solve the task but every time I get wrong. Does anyone can help me with the task and placing the ornament correctly?

Sonichka is Miss M's best friend. She has been admitted to the best university in the distant and progressive country of Noteandia. Unfortunately, Miss M misses her friend very much, so she decided to make a gift for Sonichka while she is studying in another country.

Today is Sonichka's birthday, but since Sonichka will return a bit later, and Miss M has some time, she decided to make a gift.

Miss M decided that she wants to learn cross-stitching and make ornaments on a vishivanka, which will be a gift for Sonichka to give when she returns, but she doesn't know where to start at all. So, she came up with the idea to write a program that will create an ornament of the required width and length, which she can then use as an example for embroidery.

An embroidered shirt is a rectangle n×m. The ornaments are two rays that come out from the upper corners of the shirt and have angles of 45
∘
. The ray reflects when it touches the vertical edge. When the ray touches the bottom edge, it disappears. For a visual example, you can look at the examples below.

Help Miss M learn cross-stitching and give a beautiful embroidered shirt to the lovely Sonichka for her birthday by writing such a program that, given the width n and length m, will output an example of the ornament.

Input
The first line contains two integers n and m (3≤n,m≤1000) — the height and width, respectively.

Output
Output the ornament of size n×m.

**Examples**

```
Input
6 4
Answer
x..x
.xx.
.xx.
x..x
.xx.
.xx.


Input #1
12 5

Answer #1
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
x...x
.x.x.
..x..
.x.x.
```

My version of code that doesn't work properly for the first example:

```
def create_ornament(n, m):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if (i + j) % 4 == 0 or (i - j) % 4 == 0:
                print("x", end="")
            else:
                print(".", end="")
        print()

n, m = map(int, input().split())
create_ornament(n, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not write code for you, because this is an exercise, but let's think this through together. You receive two inputs:

- `n`: the number of lines
- `m`: the number of characters

We also know that a line has 1 or 2 **x** inside of it and the rest is **.**.

Your first line has the x's at the edges of the output. The second line moves the x's "inside" by one compared to the first one and so on until the x's arrive to the middle and then they start to go outside until the initial state is reached.

So, the question is: where the x's should be on each line. You start with positions 0 and m - 1. Then you go to positions 1 and m - 2.

Note that each cycle if of a length of m, so line m + 1 will start over and repeat line 1.

So in each line you are interested to know `i % m`, because that determines where your "x" should be.

For an `m` of 4

if i % m is:

- 0: then x is on 0 and 3
- 1: then x is on 1 and 2
- 2: then x is on 1 and 2
- 3: then x is on 0 and 3

For an `m` of 5

if i % m is:

- 0: then x is on 0 and 4
- 1: then x is on 1 and 3
- 2: then x is on 2
- 3: then x is on 1 and 3
- 4: then x is on 0 and 4

For any `i % m` you know that its distance from the middle will be the most important for you. Since we start any period from maximum distance and end up with maximum distance, we need to compute the difference between `i % m` and the middle, which is

```
min(abs(m / 2 - 1 - i % m), abs(m / 2 - i % m))
```

when `m` is pair and

```
abs(m / 2 - i % m)
```

when `m` is odd.

Now, when you iterate with `j`, see its distance from the middle with the formulas I have given you above for pair and odd `m`. If it matches the distance of `i % m`, then you will need an **x**; otherwise, you will need a **.**.